# make all the other widget flatbuttons chage their colour when one is pressed on flutter

Tags: button, flutter

i have some buttons that i need to be able to press only one and the rest should change their colour,

in order to make the code smaller i extracted the widget to make it reusable, but when i select a button it get the colour changed but it does not refresh the state of the other buttons.

if i dont extract the button method and make use of duplicate code inside the Row, then it works.

What im missing?

```
int numOfTime = 60;

class NumOfTime extends StatefulWidget {
  const NumOfTime({
    Key key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _NumOfTimeState createState() => _NumOfTimeState();
}

class _NumOfTimeState extends State<NumOfTime> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15, top: 5),
            child: Text(
              'Δευτερόλεπτα',
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
            )),
        Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 2, left: 10, right: 10, bottom: 10),
          decoration: myBoxDecoration(),
          child: Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 5),
                  child: Icon(Icons.timer)),
              CustomButton(
                number: 30,
              ),
              CustomButton(
                number: 45,
              ),
              CustomButton(
                number: 60,
              ),
              CustomButton(
                number: 75,
              ),
              CustomButton(
                number: 90,
              ),
              Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class CustomButton extends StatefulWidget {
  final int number;
  const CustomButton({
    Key key,
    final int number,
  }) : this.number = number;

  @override
  _CustomButtonState createState() => _CustomButtonState(number);
}

class _CustomButtonState extends State<CustomButton> {
  final int number;
  _CustomButtonState(this.number);

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Expanded(
      flex: 1,
      child: FlatButton(
          shape:
              RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6.0)),
          disabledColor: number == numOfTime ? Colors.black : Colors.white,
          highlightColor: number == numOfTime ? Colors.black : Colors.white,
          color: number == numOfTime ? Colors.black : Colors.white,
          child: Text(
            '$number',
            style: TextStyle(
                color: number == numOfTime ? Colors.white : Colors.black,
                fontSize: 13),
          ),
          onPressed: () {
            numOfTime = number;
            setState(() {});
          }),
    );
  }
}
```

i expect to see all the other buttons change their color back to white if one is selected.

i also tried to pass null onPressed to make it disabled, but i dont see any change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a common error, you have many options to solve this, I will show you the easy way with minimum modifications.

You need to refresh the parent widget ( the widget which contains the buttons) , because you need to refresh all of your buttons again.

So, this is your code fixed:

```
    class _NumOfTimeState extends State<NumOfTime> {
      _onPressed() {
        setState(() {});
      }

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15, top: 5),
                child: Text(
                  'Δευτερόλεπτα',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                )),
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 2, left: 10, right: 10, bottom: 10),
              //decoration: myBoxDecoration(),
              child: Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 5),
                      child: Icon(Icons.timer)),
                  CustomButton(
                    number: 30,
                    onButtonPressed: _onPressed,
                  ),
                  CustomButton(
                    number: 45,
                    onButtonPressed: _onPressed,
                  ),
                  CustomButton(
                    number: 60,
                    onButtonPressed: _onPressed,
                  ),
                  CustomButton(
                    number: 75,
                    onButtonPressed: _onPressed,
                  ),
                  CustomButton(
                    number: 90,
                    onButtonPressed: _onPressed,
                  ),
                  Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        );
      }
    }

    class CustomButton extends StatefulWidget {
      final int number;
      final VoidCallback onButtonPressed;
      const CustomButton({
        Key key,
        final int number,
        this.onButtonPressed,
      }) : this.number = number;

      @override
      _CustomButtonState createState() => _CustomButtonState(number);
    }

    class _CustomButtonState extends State<CustomButton> {
      final int number;
      _CustomButtonState(this.number);

      @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
      }

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Expanded(
          flex: 1,
          child: FlatButton(
              shape:
                  RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6.0)),
              disabledColor: number == numOfTime ? Colors.black : Colors.white,
              highlightColor: number == numOfTime ? Colors.black : Colors.white,
              color: number == numOfTime ? Colors.black : Colors.white,
              child: Text(
                '$number',
                style: TextStyle(
                    color: number == numOfTime ? Colors.white : Colors.black,
                    fontSize: 13),
              ),
              onPressed: () {
                numOfTime = number;
                widget.onButtonPressed();
              }),
        );
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use streams that you subscribe to in your button. I wrote an article for this exact problem [here](https://www.filledstacks.com/snippet/use-rx-dart-in-flutter-to-synchronize-ui).

Basically when one button is tapped you broadcast it's id on a stream. At the same time all your buttons (your CustomWidget) listens to the stream. When a new id comes on the stream you check if the current button is the one pressed, if it's not you disable it. If it is you leave it enabled.

Too much code to paste here, but the article (only 2 minutes long) describes everything.